# Number of iterations with the optim and optimx function in R

Tags: r, optimization

To minimise the function with respect to 2 parameters, I use either optim or optimx function in R, both with the Nelder-Mead method. I fixed the itnmax and the maxit to 1 for the optim and optimx function respectively, but this takes me a lot of time to solve it.
Does itnmax=1 or maxit=1 really mean 1 iteration step? Because if yes, it wouldn't take so much time.

Here is the optim function with the f function to minimize. Evaluating the function takes approximatively 10 seconds. I stopped the optimization after 10 minutes, because it still wasn't done.

```
parmin=optimx(c(3,0.04),fn=f,method="Nelder-Mead",itnmax=1)
```

Comment: Pleaese review [mcve].

Comment: It would be too long to introduce my function, which is quite complex. I just ask what itnmax really represents and if it should be quicker in my case, knowing that my function takes approximatively 10s to be evaluated.

Comment: Well,   how long is a long time?  It should take d+2 = 4 function evaluations for one step in d-dimensions. Is it taking much more than 40 seconds?

Comment: Look at my question, I added some information. It takes more than 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm upvoting because this is a useful question, but for future reference I do think you could have provided a reproducible example (e.g., see my answer ...)

Comment: @Ben: The reason why I didn't write a reproducible example is that I thought the problem came from my function f, which is really too complex to write it up here. But as it seems that the same problem occurs with the function you provided, I agree that I should change my question and integrate your function in a reproducible example.

Comment: Do you mean "with my *solution*" (i.e. use `control(kkt=FALSE,starttests=FALSE)` as specified below)? If so (and you used the instrumentation as well), how many total evaluations were used? Please clarify.

Comment: Well, if the problem did come from your function, then we would need to know it in order to answer the question. It can't work both ways: "I have a problem with a complex function but it's too complex to show and I can't reduce its complexity and preserve the problem" is essentially unsolvable ...

Comment: Sorry, I should have edited something, because I don't find where I said "with my solution".

Comment: You say "the same problem occurs with the function you provided". Do you mean that it takes 8 minutes to run `optimx(...)` when the objective function takes approximately 1 second (i.e. `Sys.sleep(1)` ... the rest of the objective function should take << 1 second) ? Or did you use `Sys.sleep(10)`, as appeared in the original version of my answer?  If the latter, then 8 minutes is about what I would expect.  The two-minute difference probably occurs because Richardson extrapolation could take longer with a more complex function [i.e. surface farther from quadratic]

Comment: In any case, if you specify `control(...)` as below, I would expect `optimx()` to evaluate your objective function about 5 times when `itnmax=1`. If not, please edit your question accordingly ...

Comment: also ... if results are weird please specify which version of `optimx` you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Test function with evaluation counter, enforced delay (I set it to 1 second), and tracing output (for the impatient among us)

```
eval_count <- 0
f <- function(x) { 
     cat(".")
     eval_count <<- eval_count + 1
     Sys.sleep(1) 
     return(sum(x^2) )
}

parmin=optimx(c(3,0.04),fn=f,method="Nelder-Mead",itnmax=1)
eval_count ## 52
```

So at ~10 seconds per evaluation I would have expected your function to take about 520 seconds (but possibly longer depending on details - see below).

So what's going on here? The main issue is that `optimx` is computing the Hessian by an expensive method (Richardson extrapolation: see `?numDeriv::grad`) in order to do stricter convergence testing.  It also does some tests at startup. `?optimx` says (under the details of control parameters):

> kkt =FALSE if we do NOT want to test the Kuhn, Karush, Tucker optimality conditions. The default is TRUE. However, because the Hessian computation may be very slow ...

If your objective function is far from quadratic, Richardson extrapolation could be a little more expensive (more function calls required), which could explain the difference between 8.7 minutes (=52*10/60) and 10 minutes.  Or, if your function takes 12 seconds rather than 10, that would also bring the expectation to > 10 minutes for 52 function evaluations.

```
eval_count <- 0
parmin=optimx(c(3,0.04),fn=f,method="Nelder-Mead",itnmax=1,
      control=list(starttests=FALSE,kkt=FALSE))
eval_count ## 5
```

Comment: Ok, I thought that Nelder-Mead method didn't compute the Hessian, and that was what makes this method quite fast. Does the Nelder-Mead method does the same in the optim package?